# set socket buffer size for receive and send buffer

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket, setsockopt

How can I set the socket buffer size for a UNIX socket file descriptor in C? 
I understand setsockopt is probably the system call involved...
Can anyone give an example of how to use it, the one's I have found do not explain how to set the buffer size?

Comment: What is wrong with the defaults

Comment: You found examples of how to set the socket buffer size that don't explain how to set the socket buffer size?

Comment: @EJP - yeah, exactly.  It's one call, [Clarkson], how hard can it be?

Comment: Googling 'UNIX setbuffersize': 'About 24,400 results'.

Comment: nevermind figured it out, @EJP- I found how to use setsockopt() not how to set socket buffer size. Anyhow accepting TonyB's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04 Linux check out `man 7 socket`, and specifically look at `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF`.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically:

```
#include <socket.h>

int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int sz = 1024;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sz, sizeof(sz)); // Send buffer 1K
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &sz, sizeof(sz)); // Receive buffer 1K
```

Don't forget to check that `setsockopt()` returns 0 on success. Otherwise, `errno` will tell you what went wrong.